# How to change the style of an element using selenium

Tags: java, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have an image in my code. When I click on it, I want its style to be changed.
The field looks like this :

```
<a class="myField" href="#" style="left: 0%;"></a>
```

I can get the element by class and click on it. But I don't know how to change the style.

```
WebElement webelement = driver.findElement(By.className("myField"));
webelement.click();
//Change the style to 'left:40%;'
```

I am new to selenium. Any help appreciated.

Comment: You should do it in javascript/css, why do you want selenium to do it ? it would be just there for selenium execution not for the real life app

Comment: @JigarJoshi Exactly. I am already doing it in my app using jQuery. But I need to automate the scenario using selenium

Comment: So you shouldn't be changing it by selenium, you should be just clicking and let javascript change it and you should assert it in selenium test, unless I am misunderstanding your question

Comment: @JigarJoshi.. Basically I have a slider with upper and lower limits. When I click on a particular position the upper limit image is repositioned at that place. While using selenium, if I click the upper limit image, it remains at the same place.

Comment: Did you check why from browser it is driving on ? (except if it is headless)

Comment: @JigarJoshi you are reasonably near to it. I don't need to change the style if I am able to click at the right position... With this the question arises, how do I click at a particular position on a long image using selenium ?

Comment: something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12974488/selenium-webdriver-move-mouse-to-point

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using `javascriptExecutor`:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.getElementsByName('myField')[0].style.left='40%'");
```