# Physically moving cursor to a Web Element in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework, pyautogui

I would like to physically move the cursor to a web element (not simulate it) and Hold shift key and click another element by an offset.

I have got the hold shift key and clicking the 2nd element, using pyautogui:

```
import pyautogui

pyautogui.keyDown('shift')
pyautogui.moveRel(0, 62)
pyautogui.click()
pyautogui.keyUp('shift')
```

My problem is moving the mouse physically to that original web element, then performing the above code. Pyautogui gives the option to move to absolute x,y coordinators, but it won't work in my case because the web element's absolute position changes.

Any idea how can I do this? preferably in python (pyautogui, selenium, etc)?

Browser is chrome and OS is OS X.

Comment: Why can't you simulate the click? What are you trying to do by holding down the shift key, open a link in a new window?

Comment: I am not trying to open a new window. There is a table in the webpage that lists some devices. One of the columns is Device ID (e.g. 1234). Sometimes there are devices with same IDs right below each other in the column. E.g. there are 3 rows with DeviceID column set to 1234. I want to select entries with the same DeviceID. Manually, I click the first 1234, hold shift key, and click the third 1234. The problem is if I simulate the click by identifying the DeviceID number (1234), the first 1234 will always be selected. Hope I have clarified what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: [This]:(http://imgur.com/FsW6rOB) is the table with item one selected. [link]:(http://imgur.com/aGsCs9T) is where all of the items are selected.

Answer (score 0):

(I can only talk for selenium with this one unfortunately)

You can use Selenium Actions for this, i.e. (sample is C#)

```
new Actions(driver)
    .MoveToElement(element1)
    .KeyDown(Keys.Shift)
    .MoveByOffset(offset)
    .Click(element2)
    .KeyUp(Keys.Shift)
    .Perform();
```

If you're using Java there is also (from what I've read) some concept of a Robot for these kind of things, i.e. see this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/12978079/3110529

Comment: Regretfully selenium actions also "simulate" it, they won't do what OP is asking; looking at the Robot class, it's part of the java.awt package, so if it does the trick, that'll probably work only for local execution, not in a remote no JVM and access to it)

Comment: @Todor This is purely anecdotal, and might not be exactly the same, but I have a test which does something similar, i.e. a menu only appears when you 'move' the cursor over another element.

For this I use `new Actions(Driver).MoveToElement(widget).Build().Perform();`

this causes the hover menu to open up and then I can access the options within it.

Comment: I am not saying it doesn't trigger the action, in the contrary, I also use it for hover successfully. What I am saying is that it does not physically move the cursor, which was what the OP asked for. I myself don't know how to help him, this my activity for the question is only in the comments :)

Comment: @Todor I get you now; I wasn't intending to come across as argumentative there, sorry! Hopefully OP can get the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the [ImageHorizonLibrary](http://eficode.github.io/robotframework-imagehorizonlibrary/doc/ImageHorizonLibrary.html#Move%20To) from [Eficode](http://www.eficode.com/home) might be of use to you. The library works on Linux and Windows and moves the mouse.

Below is an example script of a two step mouse move. The Library has a number of click option [Keywords](http://eficode.github.io/robotframework-imagehorizonlibrary/doc/ImageHorizonLibrary.html) as well, as that seems logical next step action.

```
*** Settings ***
Library    ImageHorizonLibrary

*** Test Cases ***

Mouse Test
    Sleep    2Sec
    Move To    345     345
    Sleep    2Sec
    Move To    1800    720
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continue to use PyAutoGUI, I would recommend using the image recognition feature. Take a screenshot of the element in the webpage and crop the screenshot to just the element (using MS Paint or even an online cropping tool).

Then run:

```
>>> x, y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('croppedscreenshot.png')
>>> pyautogui.moveTo(x, y)
>>> pyautogui.keyDown('shift')
>>> pyautogui.click(x, y)
>>> pyautogui.keyUp('shift')
```

This is, of course, fragile and error-prone. It relies on the element being visible on the screen, and will likely not work if you are using a different browser than the screenshot was made from.

It's a much better idea to use Selenium or another such tool.

Comment: I actually looked into the image recognition feature, but I get an error which sounds like it didn't find the image:  x, y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('test.png')
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable