# How can i move to an offset using in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Problem: Its that when you hover down with it in a while loop, after once, it changes again its co-ordinates back to 0,0. Thus, in a while it does not goes down, it first goes up and then goes down

Here is my code:

```
while True
    actions.move_by_offset(0,72).perform()
```

How can i make it move to the offset, and not let it go up (reset to 0,0) and directly goes down

Comment: Maybe this question helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12974488/selenium-webdriver-move-mouse-to-point

Comment: Unfortunately, no this can't help, but thanks