# How to move Selenium mouse to exact X, Y without telling which element has to be clicked using Javascript/Typescript?

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, automation, browser-automation

How to move Selenium mouse to exact X, Y without telling which element has to be clicked using Javascript/Typescript? I can't find anythin which can help me with that. Maybe some workaround?

Comment: No @RyanWilson , I need to use Selenium behavior

Comment: [selenium-webdriver-move-mouse-to-point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12974488/selenium-webdriver-move-mouse-to-point)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
const X = 5;
const Y = 50; 
document.elementFromPoint(X, Y).click();
```

Thats will click on (x, y) coordinates fro the document.

**Edit:**

**Note - The (X,Y) from the top left!**

If you write this in selenium javascript you should use like this:

```
driver.navigate().to("https://www.youtube.com").then(()=>{
    driver.executeScript('document.elementFromPoint(25,25).click()')
})
```

You have to use the `executeScript` to get the document element - maybe there is a better way but its should work

Comment: That's do something, is it moving from top right corner or top left?

Comment: @r2d23 top left